# jQuery .load() - getting td contents from the DOM

Tags: jquery, dom, load, innerhtml

I am reading a table row from one page, and then trying to put the cell contents into various elements on a second page. I have it sort of working, but I'd like to (a) do it properly, and (b) get rid of the extra tags I've picked up.
So my method is....

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function(){
    $('#result_row').load('schedule.html #schedule_list tr:eq(1)',function(){
        var date = $('td:eq(0)',this);
        $('#date').html(date);
        var title = $('td:eq(0)',this);
        $('#title').html(title);
        var speaker = $('td:eq(0)',this);
        $('#speaker').html(speaker);
    });             
  }); 
});
```

and then I have 
  `<div class= "upcoming">
    Next Talk: <span id="speaker"></span> - <span id="title"></span>    (<span id="date"></span>)
        </div>
        <span id="result_row"></span>`

So this works to a point but I have a distinct feeling I'm doing it inefficiently (or wrong) as I'm a jQuery novice. In particular, having an empty `<span id="result_row">` seems incorrect. More importantly, it also imports the `<td>` tags into the `<span>` elements, which I'd like to avoid. All attempts to innerHTML failed (e.g. `var date = $('td:eq(0)',this).innerHTML;`

Thanks for any help,

Nick

**EDIT**: So now I can either do this three times

```
var date = $('td:eq(0)',this).text();
$('#date').text(date);
```

to avoid getting the `<td>` tags. Or I can do this

```
var data = $.find('td',this);
$('#date').html(data[0]);
$('#speaker').html(data[1]);
$('#title').html(data[2]);
```

which I think looks a lot clearer (and I assume the last three lines could be done in one). Sadly .text() doesn't seem to work, so I'm stuck with `<td>`'s in my output.

Comment: What is this 3 times? `$('td:eq(0)',this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get the data inside the `td`s, use `.html()` or `.text()`. eg:

```
var date = $('td:eq(0)',this).html();
```

In terms of doing it properly, loading html from a page (scraping) is rarely doing it properly. You should be getting the data from another source, such as json provided & formatted by the server etc. But if you must do it, your code looks fine to me :)

Comment: Thanks Christian for the quick response. 
I did try the .html() but couldn't get it to work. The .text() works perfectly though.
I assumed it wasn't the most recommended/wisest technique but it's just a basic, quick site for a friend. They are updating a table of lectures (and that's the total of their HTML knowledge). The university server allows only HTML. Therefore, I figured that the simplest way to show the 'next' lecture on the home page was to just grab it from the table......

Answer (score 0):

In terms of efficiency, this is how I would do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var resultRow = $('#resultRow');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'schedule.html'
    })
    .done(function(response) {
        var context = $('#schedule_list tr:eq(1)'),
            data = context.find('td:eq(0)');

        $('#date, #title, #speaker').html(data).appendTo(resultRow);
    });
});
```

I noticed you had 2 `document.ready`s. Removed one of them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick response Eli. I tried this method but it doesn't seem to work. From what I can tell (from my novice position) the variable context is empty. Also, the last line doesn't display anything, even when I explicitly set the values of data with a new test array. If I use a key for data, I then see the corresponding test array values in the three elements.

I really like the concept of this code, especially the use of an array that I should have spotted myself, I just can't get it work.